# Error 3001 on Recordset.AddNew with predefined array

Tags: vba

Using the instructions [here](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_ADODB_recordset_en.html#L_5.7), I've created a macro to read in two separate sets of data into a single recordset. This works fine:

```
Sub test

Dim Base as ADODB.RecordSet
Set Base = New ADODB.RecordSet
 
Set1 = Range("A1:B3")              'Change to Dynamic Named Range
Set2 = Range("D1:E4")              'Change to Dynamic Named Range
ColCount = Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)    'This is what I change later

With Base
    For i = 1 to UBound(Set1, 2)
        .Fields.Append Set1(1,i), 129, 120
    Next i

    For i = 1 to UBound(Set2, 2)
        .Fields.Append Set2(1,i), 129, 120
    Next i

    .Open
    .AddNew _
        ColCount, _
        Array(Set1(2,1), Set1(2,2), Set1(2,3), _
            Set2(2,1), Set2(2,2), Set2(2,3), Set2(2,4))
    .Close
End With

End Sub
```

What I want to do is to let the number of columns be dynamic. I tried the following change to the ColCount array, but I get a 3001 error:

```
Dim ColCount() as Variant
    For a=1 to UBound(Set1, 2) + UBound(Set2, 2)
        ReDim Preserve Colcount(a)
        ColCount(a)=a-1
    Next a
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... it's as simple as changing the line to update the array length to:

```
ReDim Preserve Colcount(1 to a)
```